# ##[error]Required: 'ConnectedServiceNameARM' input --- Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

**##[error]Required: 'ConnectedServiceNameARM' input**

This is in Azure DevOps using YAML inline script.

1. Need help with what to enter to fix this error?  I am really new at YAML.  This is a inline YAML and what tried seems to break the YAML script.  The ConnectedServiceNameARM is just the Azure Subscription name?  My service connection in azure devops has a working azure subscription name so I am wondering what is wrong?
2. Also need this YAML code to run so that the output file is placed in agent/_work/_tasks folder and not the artifacts folder. How would I move the file from the _tasks/Powershell folder to something that can be copied to share?

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: 'CloudUiPath001'
  demands:
  - agent.name -equals UiPathAgent01

steps:

- task: AzurePowerShell@3

  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'

  inputs:

  

    ScriptType: InlineScript

    Inline: |
     $filePath='C:\Program Files (x86)\UiPath\Studio'
     $dir=(New-Object -com scripting.filesystemobject).getFolder($filePath).ShortPath
     $ProjectFilePath= "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_TESTREPO7/project.json"
     $ExecutableFilePath=$dir+"\UiPath.Studio.CommandLine.exe"
     
     $OutputFilePath=".\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')-Workflow-Analysis.json"
     
     #This was an attempt to write the filename to a pipeline variable: Feel free to continue on this path if possible
     Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=jsonFilePath]$OutputFilePath"
     
     Write-Output "$(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss') - STARTED - Workflow Analyzer CLI Script"
     
     $Command = "$ExecutableFilePath analyze -p $ProjectFilePath"
     Invoke-Expression $Command | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFilePath
     
     Write-Output "$(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss') - COMPLETED - Workflow Analyzer CLI Script"

    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

How do I fix his error within a INLINE YAML script. I am new to YAML and when I tried to enter a input I got errors.

**##[error]Required: 'ConnectedServiceNameARM' input**

Answer (score 9):

According to your `AzurePowerShell` task definition, you don’t seem to specify the `azureSubscription` field.

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: xxx
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

You can click the `Settings` shown in the figure below to specify the subscription.

[image]

[image]

About Azure PowerShell task, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) for details.

Comment: Can we hide the azure subscription? For security I would like to hide those values. I tried to use variables from the pipeline but it seems that is not doing it right

Answer (score 0):

to go around this error change from  **task: AzurePowerShell@5** to **pwsh**:

```
- pwsh: |
    InlineScript
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
```